# Cordova / PhoneGap push notifications without a server

Tags: javascript, android, jquery-mobile, cordova, push-notification

I'm looking for a way to show alerts when the app is minimized or the screen is locked.

It appears that I **have** to use the [official PushPlugin](https://github.com/phonegap-build/PushPlugin#automatic_installation) to make it happen - looks like I'll have to register the device and then wait for the notifications to come through.

Question: Is there a way to push notifications from the app itself to the lock
   screen that does not use `PushPlugin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We use [parse.com](http://parse.com) for push notifications with our cordova projects. You don't actually "need" a plugin for cordova, you glue parse.com libs with your native side. It is pretty straightforward. At the end, you have a parse.com account and an interface to send push notifications to your clients.

Now I read your question again, if you want to set a timer and send a "local notification" from the app itself to the os, it is not called push notification, its name is local notification and there is a plugin for that too.

Answer (score 2):

This link below discuss 2 possible solutions for your case

**SingalR**

Pros:

- Well suited for real-time delivery where time or receiving
  notifications from the server is important.
- Web clients are supported by all major browsers, IE8+, FireFox,
  Chrome, Safari and Android WebView, iOS Safari, IE mobile, so they
  are working well.
- Solution could be written in JS, without need for the knowing

Cons:

- required dedicated server, but possible hosting with shared hosting
  probably, since not performance hungry.
- In Cordova particularly requires manual connection management for
  better user experience, instead of relying on the re-connection
  mechanism which SignalR provides (This is required for iOS which
  could drop network connection for battery preserving, on Android not
  an issue so far).

  **Azure Notification Hub**

Pros:

- Use existing infrastructure of Google, Apple and MS to deliver
  notifications to the user and each of them not guarantee immediate
  delivery of the notifications. You have to read each platforms
  separately:

  - Apple: Quality Service section of APNS docs
  - Google: GCM Advanced Topics
- No need for the dedicated server

Cons:

- No guarantee for the immediate deleivery.
- Required working with each native platform's languages. (There
  excellent plugin for Cordova
  https://github.com/sgrebnov/cordova-plugin-azure-notificationhub, but
  it is does not allow receiving notifications when application paused
  on Android and don't have 64 bit build on iOS)

**Source** :[phonegap-push-signalr-vs-azure-notification-hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25840599/server-to-phonegap-push-signalr-vs-azure-notification-hub)

hope it helps.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @JordanD Part of the answer is written not only the link . just didn't want to repeat !

Answer (score 1):

You can always make the "old and good" manual -inverse- push.

You can make a Service in the App that checks every hour (or so) to the server for notifications.

That requires a lot of programming + lot of resources in server + lot of network traffic in the phone... but NO REGISTRATION!!!

I wouldn't recommend this, but since you don't want to register...

Comment: Could you please discuss the details of this approach a bit more?

Comment: You can add a function in your app that runs in the backend (silently) that every hour (or so) makes an ajax request to your sever asking "are there notifications to this user?". If yes, send the message, if not keep silent until next hour (or so)